# Mysql Selecting the average value of a column from things that are stored in 3 tables

Tags: mysql, select

I am fairly new with databases and I am starting with mysql.

I have 4 tables (`movie`, `genre`,  `movieGenre` and `movieRating`):

`movie`:

```
CREATE TABLE `movie` (
  `movieId` INT NOT NULL,
  `title` VARCHAR(155) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`movieId`)
);
```

`genre`

```
CREATE TABLE `genre` (
  `code` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `genre` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`code`)
);
```

`movieGenre`

```
CREATE TABLE `movieGenre` (
  `movieId` INT,
  `genreId` INT,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_movieGenre_movie` FOREIGN KEY (`movieId`) REFERENCES `movie`(`movieId`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_movieGenre_genre` FOREIGN KEY (`genreId`) references `genre`(`code`)
);
```

and `movieRating`

```
CREATE TABLE `movieRating` (
  `userId` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `movieId` INT NOT NULL,
  `rating` FLOAT NOT NULL,
  `date` DATE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_movieRating_user` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `user`(`userId`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_movieRating_movie` FOREIGN KEY (`movieId`) REFERENCES `movie`(`movieId`)
);
```

I need to find the average rate for each movie genre, sorted in descended average rating value and if a genre does not have any associated rating, it should be reported with 0 ratings value

I am lost. I don't know how to achieve this result. Could you please help me?

I have figured out how to find the avg rate for each movie but I don't know how to change this so I find for each genre:

```
SELECT `movie`.`movieId`, AVG(`movieRating`.`rating`) FROM `movie`
INNER JOIN `movieRating` ON `movie`.`movieId` = `movieRating`.`movieId`
GROUP BY `movieRating`.`movieId`
ORDER BY AVG(`movieRating`.`rating`) DESC;
```

Comment: From your database design, I assume you plan to let certain movies fall into more than one genre?

Comment: this looks like a home work question without any try

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Yea, some movies are on multiple categories

Comment: @nbk It is, I am not hiding. I have been trying for the past hour. I figured out how to find the average rate for each movie. I will edit the question!

Comment: OK, when I wrote the Query, I notice that the `genre` table doesn't have an `id`, so there's no way to know what `genreId`, in the `movieGenre` table, refers to. Apart from that it is a rather straightforward query.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Do I have to use a nested subquery? Like this: select * from( select _etc_) ?

Comment: I don't know. The problem I have is that I have no data. Normally I would say, no, you don't need it, but you want to report an average for each genre, even when there's no data, and I haven't worked on that because of the missing `id` in the `genre` table. It might require a sub-select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have put an ID in your genre table, otherwise I can't make this work. So, it has become:

```
CREATE TABLE `genre` (
  `genreId` INT,
  `code` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `genre` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`code`)
);
```

And I have to make the assumption that all the genres are defined in this table. I'll take this table as a base, and, as you suggested use a subquery:

```
SELECT
  genre.code,
  genre.genre,
  (<my sub select comes here>)
FROM
  genre;
```

This basically gets you a list of all genres. Now it is up to the subquery to give the average rate for the movies in each genre. That subquery could look something like this:

```
SELECT AVG(movieRating.rating)
FROM movieRating
JOIN movie ON movie.movieId = movieRating.movieId  
JOIN movieGenre ON movieGenre.movieId = M.movieId  
WHERE movieGenre.genreId = genre.genreId;
```

I kept it very simple. We start with the average we want, from `movieRating`, and work through the `movie` and `movieGenre` tables to get to the `genreId` in that last table. Notice the `genre.genreId` which comes from the main query. We are implicitly grouping by `genreId`.

Now you can put this subselect in the main query, but that still doesn't solve the situation in which there is not rating to take an average from. It would result in `NULL`, meaning: no result. That is almost good enough, but you could put a `IFNULL()` around it to get a proper zero result.

The total query would then become this:

```
SELECT
  genre.code,
  genre.genre,
  IFNULL((SELECT AVG(movieRating.rating)
          FROM movieRating
          JOIN movie ON movie.movieId = movieRating.movieId  
          JOIN movieGenre ON movieGenre.movieId = M.movieId  
          WHERE movieGenre.genreId = genre.genreId), 0) AS Average
FROM
  genre;
```

I can't guarantee this will work since I cannot test it, and testing is everything when writing queries.

Comment: Thank you for this thorough explanation. I learned a lot from this!!

Answer (score 0):

You should left join all tables and then group by gerne

```
SELECT `genre`,AVG(IFNULL(`rating`,0)) avgrate
FROM `movie` m
LEFT JOIN `movieRating` mr ON m.`movieId` = mr.`movieId`
LEFT JOIN movieGenre mg ON mg.`movieId` = m.`movieId` 
LEFT JOIN `genre` g ON g.`code` = mg.`genreId`
GROUP BY `genre`
```

I  general produce data for your tables, and then start by joing the tables, and see f you get the result you want, if not change the joins to LET Join one by one till you get the result you want, of course you need ro calculate teh avg from 3 or 4 movies